# mean, max, min functions with ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I have a  large meteorological data set with half hour values. I'm using the ddply function to then create daily values (means, sums, etc), however i am experiencing problems with the getting min and max values! For some values e.g. air temperature i would like to extract the daily mean, min and max, however the data frame returned gives me min and max values which are the same as the mean. Could somebody have a look at the command i wrote to see if they spot any errors?

```
HFTda <- ddply (HFT, .(Year, DOY),summarise, 
                Temp = mean (Temp, na.rm = F), 
                Tmax = max (Temp, na.rm = F),
                Tmin = min (Temp, na.rm = F),
                RHmax = max (RH.x, na.rm = F), 
                RHmin = min (RH.x, na.rm = F),
                VPD = mean (VPD.x, na.rm = F), 
                Grad = mean (GradInc2, na.rm = F), 
                Gex = mean (Gex, na.rm = F),
                Prec = sum (Prec, na.rm = F), 
                H = mean (HFill, na.rm = F), 
                LE = mean (LEFill, na.rm = F), 
                NEE = mean (co2_fluxFill, na.rm = F), 
                ET = mean (h2o_fluxFill, na.rm = F), 
                SWout = mean (YB5214h, na.rm = F))
```

Comment: NB: The daily split is based on the year and day number (DOY)

Comment: Please give some reproducible example. My advice is to put your call to summarise in an anonymous function, and put a browser call inside so that you can inspect all your values

Comment: I second @KarlForner Add the output from `dput( head( HFT ) )` to the question, in a code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the lack of a reproducible example I think I have an idea; I think the problem is that you're taking the mean of `temp` (and overwriting the value locally) before you try to get its min and max:

Preliminaries:

```
d <- data.frame(day=rep(1:2,each=4),Temp=1:8)
library(plyr)
```

Stripped-down example:

```
ddply(d, .(day), summarise,
   Temp = mean (Temp),
   minTemp = min(Temp))
 ##   day Temp minTemp
 ## 1   1  2.5     2.5
 ## 2   2  6.5     6.5
```

The simplest workaround is just to change the order:

```
 ddply(d, .(day), summarise,
   minTemp = min(Temp),
   Temp = mean (Temp))
##   day minTemp Temp
## 1   1       1  2.5
## 2   2       5  6.5
```

Alternatively (perhaps better) you can refer to your mean variable as `meanTemp` ...

http://r4stats.com/2013/01/22/comparing-tranformation-styles/ is related (apparently `summarise` does `mutate`-style evaluation)

Comment: Perfect! Yes the problem is because the the name of the mean value is the same as that of the raw data, this is calculated first, as the ddply function does the calculation in the given order! Yeah, the easiest solution is to just change the name to "aveTemp" or "meanTemp"

Comment: P.s. Sorry for the lack of an example dataframe. I just was sure the problem was in the code itself and though those working with ddply would recognise the problem ion the code. Anyways, next time I have a question I'll be sure to put up a simplified example of the dataframe in question. Thanks for solution Ben, and thanks for the comments from the others!